# How to format PGF graph axis tick numbers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to use PGF to draw graphs, and to tame the format of the numbers with which PGF labels the ticks on an axis. I observe that, by default, if the number is 10000 or more, PGF switches to scientific notation. This might indeed be suitable in some circumstances, but for some of my graphs numbers of 4 or 5 digits will fit just fine and I would prefer these. How do I suppress PGF's scientific notation in one particular `tikzpicture` environment?

I thought that putting `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` in the `axis` environment would do the trick, but no. I looked at the user manuals for TikZ and PGF and PGFplots, but couldn't find any statement which I was confident stated the correct thing to do. I have to say that I find the documentation hard to use: even if I find a keyword that seems to be relevant to the thing I want to control, it is not obvious to me what value it should be given or where the keyword should fit into the wider syntax, so it might well be that the documentation contains the answer but I didn't spot it.

Indeed, is this an XY problem, and that PGFplots is now deprecated and we should all now be using `\datavisualization` instead?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % for {axis}

\setlength{\hoffset}{-20mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{180mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-30mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{262mm}

\pgfplotsset{every tick/.append style={thick,color=black}}
\pgfplotsset{grid=major}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={thick}}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=.5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=19cm, height=72mm,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xmin=-5,xmax=10000,xtick={0,1000,...,10000},
    ymin=-40,ymax=32, ytick={-40,-35,...,30}
   ]
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) more carefully. :-)

Your problem is solved by passing `scaled ticks=false` to the `axis` environment (cf. §4.15.3, *Tick Scaling – Common Factors In Ticks* in the `pgfplots` manual):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % or some lower version if you don't have any ≥ 1.18

\pgfplotsset{
  every tick/.append style={thick, color=black},
  grid=major,
  grid style=thick,
}

\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=.5}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=19cm, height=72mm,
    axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    xmin=-5,xmax=10000,xtick={0,1000,...,10000},
    ymin=-40,ymax=32, ytick={-40,-35,...,30},
    scaled ticks=false,
   ]
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you don't want the thousands separators either, use `set thousands separator={}` as in:

```
xticklabel style={
  /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, set thousands separator={},
},
```

[image]

Seriously, Ti*k*Z & PGF, `pgfplots`, `pgfplotstable`, `tcolorbox`: all of these have very large manuals indeed, but:

- these packages all have *tons of features*, are extremely flexible;
- their manuals are full of examples with accompanying output, which obviously takes some space.

Writing manuals and keeping them up-to-date when code evolves is time-consuming, not necessarily the preferred task of programmers... but immensely useful for users. The manuals I have cited above are certainly the result of thousands of hours of work from their maintainers, and I am **very grateful** to them for doing so.

Regarding `datavisualization` versus `pgfplotstable`, I haven't followed the latest news, but my understanding—from the last time I read something on the subject—is that `pgfplots` hasn't been superseded by `datavisualization`. Please correct me if this is not the case anymore.